# "Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted" with Webpack and typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am new to typescript as well as webpack programming, so please do not take for granted too much background... Also I saw many similar questions in stack overflow, none of the solutions until now solved my problem:

I use vscode. My build produces the following warnings:

```
WARNING in ./src/amxcanvas.ts 3:24-31
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

WARNING in ./src/amxmisc.ts 3:24-31
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./src/amxcanvas.ts
```

As I get errors (module not found) when executing the resulting javascript code, I think that I should first get rid of these warnings.

I use the following webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src', '/amxcanvas.ts'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'amxcanvas.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'AmxCvs'
  }
};
```

The amxcanvas.ts file starts like that:

```
import * as drawable from "./amxdrawables";
import * as misc from "./amxmisc";

export function amxCanvasInit(canvasId:string, shapes:drawable.IDrawable[]) {
    var s = new CanvasState(document.getElementById(canvasId), shapes);
}
```

The amxmisc.ts file starts like that:

```
export function generateUUID(): string {
    return "";
}

var gripSize:number = 7;
```

I struggle with this since nearly a week now, does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after posting, I found the solution: I am not yet completely sure about the implications, but by changing:

```
"module": "umd",
```

to

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

in tsconfig.json, the warnings are gone. I seems that umd does some weird things with require, preventing webpack's from analyzes.